# Unity mobile game crashes on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-console

Unity game is crashing on some androids. After a few minutes game starts lagging and then crashes. Here is Stack trace from Google Play Console, does someone know how to fix that?

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.MAPSGames.FingerEscape <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 0x0000000000051b7c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+168)
  #01  pc 0x00000000006d157c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+668)
  #02  pc 0x000000000001695c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::SetAborter(std::__1::function<void (char const*)>&&)::$_3::__invoke(char const*)+76)
  #03  pc 0x0000000000015f8c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+364)
  #04  pc 0x00000000002857ec  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::AddGlobalRef(art::Thread*, art::ObjPtr<art::mirror::Object>)+1924)
  #05  pc 0x000000000059add0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<false>::NewGlobalRef(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+272)
  #06  pc 0x0000000002586cfc  /data/app/~~TWASomDJJoLgoJ0Ii_lylw==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_524912634-mVCqI3Yv_FjomGEuf0ULyQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome_64.so
  #07  pc 0x00000000025869fc  /data/app/~~TWASomDJJoLgoJ0Ii_lylw==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_524912634-mVCqI3Yv_FjomGEuf0ULyQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome_64.so
  #08  pc 0x0000000003799f0c  /data/app/~~TWASomDJJoLgoJ0Ii_lylw==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_524912634-mVCqI3Yv_FjomGEuf0ULyQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome_64.so
  #09  pc 0x0000000004a0367c  /data/app/~~TWASomDJJoLgoJ0Ii_lylw==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_524912634-mVCqI3Yv_FjomGEuf0ULyQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome_64.so
  #10  pc 0x0000000004a03614  /data/app/~~TWASomDJJoLgoJ0Ii_lylw==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_524912634-mVCqI3Yv_FjomGEuf0ULyQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome_64.so (Java_J_N_MLlibBXh+28)
  #11  pc 0x0000000000180b14  /data/app/~~5n5gC1GuTVMuUN0apQKPDA==/com.google.android.webview-uUIe4oNpEtr-Yp44RGU08w==/oat/arm64/base.odex (art_jni_trampoline+116)
  #12  pc 0x00000000003221b0  /data/app/~~5n5gC1GuTVMuUN0apQKPDA==/com.google.android.webview-uUIe4oNpEtr-Yp44RGU08w==/oat/arm64/base.odex (org.chromium.base.JavaExceptionReporter.uncaughtException+80)
  #13  pc 0x000000000020aec4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+7636)
  #14  pc 0x00000000000ec490  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar (java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException+28)
  #15  pc 0x000000000020a044  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+3924)
  #16  pc 0x00000000000ec47c  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar (java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException+8)
  #17  pc 0x000000000020ae64  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+7540)
  #18  pc 0x00000000000ed702  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar (java.lang.Thread.dispatchUncaughtException+30)
  #19  pc 0x00000000002ca764  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548)
  #20  pc 0x0000000000430030  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithVarArgs<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, std::__va_list)+880)
  #21  pc 0x00000000005ab80c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<false>::CallVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+300)
  #22  pc 0x000000000045b87c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (_JNIEnv::CallVoidMethod(_jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...)+120)
  #23  pc 0x000000000045b2e0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::HandleUncaughtExceptions(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable&)+216)
  #24  pc 0x00000000004594cc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::Destroy()+456)
  #25  pc 0x00000000004587a8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadList::Unregister(art::Thread*)+132)
  #26  pc 0x00000000003da814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::DetachCurrentThread()+128)
  #27  pc 0x000000000058fccc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JII::DetachCurrentThread(_JavaVM*)+48)
  #28  pc 0x00000000000c71b8  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+984)
  #29  pc 0x00000000000025a8  /system/bin/app_process64 (main+1360)
  #30  pc 0x000000000004a040  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__libc_init+100)
```

Comment: If it's crashing in inconsistent places and inconsistent time intervals, it seems like it could be memory leak/overflow related. Maybe trying profiling it up until one of the crashes just to see if you are running out of available mem.

Comment: Upgrading to android 11, or disabling debug seem to be solutions: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/2234

Comment: I've tried testing the game without Internet connection and it didn't crash, so I assumed it was either PlayFab or AdMob crashing the game. So it looks like ads are the problem. I've tried disabling PlayFab game still crashed, I've tried putting "Frequency capping" on AdMob so the AdMob doesn't show more than 1 ad per hour to a user and game still crashed. So looks like when game sends interstitial ad requests multiple times it crashes doesn't matter if the ad shows or request stays unmatched. But I still don't know how to fix the problem.